# JIRA - Remove a transition to same status when all Status can go to a particular Status

Tags: jira, transition, status

while modelling a Jira Statusmodel for one of my Issues i need to model a transision which goes from all to a particular Status. But I dont want a loop there, as in the same Status need not go that Status. How do i remove just this loop transision?

eg. Lets say I have Status 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'

and i have an Option, from all Status you can go to 'A'. But i dont want A -> A. How do i remove this? or any other idea how i can model this? The transition name has to be the same for all B-> A, c->A, D->A

Answer (score 1):

You can use a shared transition in the workflow, or use a global transition and then hide the loop using the handy JMWE condition https://innovalog.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/JMWE/pages/171016204/Current+Status+Condition